# semigroups-terminology question

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let the element $x$ of a commutative semigroup has the property
          $x=a+b\Rightarrow a=x~$or $b=x$.
I call such an element "prime". My question is: what is the right term about such elements.

p.s. I am not an algebraist.

Answer (score 2):

The right term should rather be *irreducible* and the definition should be slightly different:
$x$ is *irreducible* if $x = \sum_{i \in I} x_i$, then there exists $i \in I$ such that $x = x_i$. The subtle difference with your definition is that if your semigroup has a neutral element $0$ (think of $\mathbb{N}$), then $0 = \sum_{i \in \emptyset} x_i$ and hence $0$ is *not* irreducible.